# Fundamental Theorem of Bifunctors

Tags: category-theory

I'm having trouble understanding the proof of the theorem on bifunctors in MacLane's CWM on page 37.

> Let $\mathcal{C}$, $\mathcal{D}$ and $\mathcal{E}$ be categories and let $ L_y : \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{E} $ and $ M_x : \mathcal{D} \rightarrow \mathcal{E} $ be parametrized functors where $ x \in \mathcal{C} $ and $ y \in \mathcal{D} $ such that $ L_y(x) = M_x(y) $ for all $x$ and $y$.
>   Then there exists a bifunctor $ F : \mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{D} \rightarrow \mathcal{E} $ such that $ F(-,y) = L_y $ and $ F(x,-) = M_x $ for all $x$ and $y$, iff for all pairs of morphisms $ f : c \rightarrow c' $ and $ g : d \rightarrow d' $ of resp. $ \mathcal{C} $ and $ \mathcal{D} $ we have
>   $$ L_{d'}(f) \circ M_c(g) = M_{c'}(g) \circ L_d(f) $$

The proof of the converse is easy, but I feel like I'm missing something on the direct one :

Since we have $ \langle f, 1_{d'} \rangle \circ \langle 1_c, g \rangle = \langle 1_{c'}, g \rangle \circ \langle f, 1_d \rangle $, we get the following commutative diagram :

$$ \require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
F(c,d) @>F(1_c,g)>> F(c,d')\\
@VF(f,1_d)VV @VVF(f,1_{d'})V\\
F(c',d) @>>F(1_{c'},g)> F(c',d')\end{CD} $$

But how can we say that $ F(1_c,-) $ is the arrow function of the $ M_c $ functor? (likewise for $ F(-, 1_d) $ and $ L_d $)

Comment: I think "$F(1_c,-)$ is the arrow function of $M_c$" is what is meant by "$F(c,-)=M_c$", and similarly "$F(-,1_d)$ is the arrow function of $L_d$" is what is meant by "$F(-,d)=L_d$". Does that make sense to you?

Comment: You mean that when you write "$F(c,-)=M_c$" it is implied that on the object level you have the equality $ F(c,-)=M_c $ and on the arrow level you have $ F(1_c,-) = M_c $?

Comment: Yes; in an equation between functors, the "-" placeholder is a variable that ranges over both the objects of the domain category and the morphisms of the domain category -- so the asserted equalities are between both the values of the two functors on objects, and the values on the functors on morphisms.

Comment: Yes but does the notation $F(c,-)$ denote the functor with arrow level function $g \mapsto F(1_c,g)$? Because to me the first notation is ambiguous since you don't know which arrow is the fixed one. I guess you could determine it by using the fact that $ F(f, 1_d) = M_c(1_d) = 1_{M_c(d)} $

Answer (score 2):

I believe Vladimir Sotirov's comment is correct: $F(c,–)=M_c$ is meant to denote that both $F(c,d)=M_cd$ for all objects $d$ of $\mathcal D$ and $F(1_c,f)=M_cf$ for all arrows $f$ of $\mathcal D$.

This is a flaw in the flow of the proof. The convention “we write b and c for the corresponding identity arrows” is only introduced in the proof, but it’s actually already used in the statement of the proposition, as $F(-,y)=L_y$ and $F(x,–)= M_x$ wouldn't make sense if $x$ and $y$ were really just the objects they’re introduced as: The right-hand sides are functors, so the left-hand sides must be able to map arrows, not just objects.